# How to use SVG <animate> for sprite animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, safari

I want to achieve the sprite animation of the bird with SVG . I already have written code for that it is working in Chrome, Edge, Firefox but not working on Safari (the bird is not animating).

```
<image  id = "bird"  href="SVG/Birds/bird_1.svg" height="250" width="500" x = "7%" y = "1%">
 <animate
      id = "birdAnim2"
      attributeName="href"
      values = "SVG/Birds/bird_1.svg;SVG/Birds/bird2.svg;SVG/Birds/bird3.svg;"
      dur="0.8s"
      begin = "indefinite"
      repeatCount="indefinite"
 />
</image>
```

I can see an image of the bird so I don't think xlink:href was the issue but it is not animating on Safari.

Comment: you can report Safari bugs [here](https://bugs.webkit.org/)

Comment: Did you try `xlink:href`? Safari didn't support the new `href` until recently: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/href#browser_compatibility

Comment: yea, I tried xlink:href but didn't work, Right now for time being I'm doing a workaround by animating from javascript only by setting its href attribute and that is working on safari.